# Unable to superimpose points on a plot via `points3D` function in `plot3D` package in R

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization, rgl

I am plotting some points using the function `scatter3D` from `plot3D` package in R. I then want to superimpose some more points using the function `points3D`. What I get instead is that the new points are plotted as they should be but the original points disappear (no superimposition).
How can I fix that?

```
library(plot3D)
n=100
set.seed(1); data=matrix(runif(4*n),ncol=4)
scatter3D(x=data[,1], y=data[,2], z=data[,3], colvar=NULL)
points3D(x=data[,1], y=data[,2], z=data[,4], col="red")
```

(Afterwards, I will add `plotrgl()` from package `plot3Drgl` to inspect the plot from various angles. Not sure if that should affect the answer to this question.)

Answer (score 0):

Including the option `add=TRUE` in `points3D` does the trick:

```
library(plot3D)
n=100
set.seed(1); data=matrix(runif(4*n),ncol=4)
scatter3D(x=data[,1], y=data[,2], z=data[,3], colvar=NULL)
points3D(x=data[,1], y=data[,2], z=data[,4], col="red", add=TRUE)
```